# How do you preview your c++ code in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, input

I am new to Visual Studdio (and C++ and the C family in general). 
How to you preview the output for a cpp file?

for example, If I script this

```
     #include <iostream> 

int main() // does 'int main' mean start the body (Like HTML's <body> ?
{
std::cout << "Hello World! ";     // prints Hello World!
std::cout << "I'm a C++ program"; // prints I'm a C++ program
}
```

Then Visual Studio's output would show:

```
    Hello World! I'm A C++ program
```

Comment: There are web services that can do something like this but Visual Studio cannot show the output without you running the software.  C++ does not work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda hard to see what exactly you are asking here. If you mean predicting code behaviour, that's not exactly possible, for many reasons. First and foremost, you're not dealing with a **scripted** language, but a relatively low-level **programming** language. Therefore, the output of your code is extremely hard to predict and is currently out of a beginner's scope.

Secondly, HTML and C/C++ are two very different things, for two very different purposes. I would recommend you not try and compare them together.

```
int main()
```

is the entry point to your program, where the computer will start executing code from.

```
<body>
```

is a tag that defines the physical area of a webpage.

If you are jumping from HTML directly to C/C++, I suggest you take a detour and learn languages such as Java, PHP or Python. It will help you understand the concepts of such languages better.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: <kbd>F5</kbd>

..or "Start Debugging" from the "Debug" menu

That is assuming you have your project setup correctly.

You can't really "preview" the output of a C++ program.  You must compile it an execute it.